# Cannot convert value of type 'NSRange'(aka'_NSRange') to expected argument type 'Range<Data.Index>' (aka 'Range<int>

Tags: swift, swift3

there. I am a beginner in Swift and am trying to convert an older program to Swift3. I´ve managed to fix a bunch of errors, but I cannot get this function to work.

```
fileprivate func extractEntitlements(_ entitlementData: Data) -> NSDictionary? {
  var originalEntitlementsData = entitlementData
  let xmlStart = "<?xml".data(using: String.Encoding.ascii, allowLossyConversion: true)
  let bytes = (originalEntitlementsData as NSData).bytes
  for i in 0...(originalEntitlementsData.count - xmlStart!.count) {
     if memcmp((xmlStart! as NSData).bytes, bytes + i, Int(xmlStart!.count)) == 0 {
        let end = originalEntitlementsData.count - i
        **originalEntitlementsData = originalEntitlementsData.subdata(in: NSMakeRange(i, end))**
        break;
     }
  }

  return NSString(data: originalEntitlementsData, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)?.propertyList() as? NSDictionary
```

}

Here is the error I get:

[image: Cannot convert value of type 'NSRange'(aka'_NSRange') to expected argument type 'Range<Data.Index>' (aka 'Range<int>')]

There are a bunch of questions regarding this error, but I am not being successful implementing a solution. Any tips on how I should proceed?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ranges are more complicated and simpler at the same time in swift.

You want `subdata(in: start..<end)`, which makes a `Range<Int>`, which is the type you need. However, in this case `start` and `end` refer to the beginning and end indexes of the range, not the location and length as you pass to `NSMakeRange()`.

Answer (score 2):

As @jrturton already said, `subdata(in:)` takes a `Range<Int>` argument,
so it should be

```
originalEntitlementsData = originalEntitlementsData.subdata(in: i..<i+end)
```

in your case. But note that all the conversions to `NSData`, taking
the `.bytes`, explicit loop and `memcmp` are not needed if you 
take advantage of the existing `range(of:)` method of `Data`:

```
var originalEntitlementsData = entitlementData
let xmlStart = "<?xml".data(using: .utf8)!
if let range = originalEntitlementsData.range(of: xmlStart) {
    originalEntitlementsData = originalEntitlementsData.subdata(in: range.lowerBound..<originalEntitlementsData.endIndex)
   // Alternatively:
   // originalEntitlementsData.removeSubrange(0..<range.lowerBound)
}
```